# Is there a danger in putting a ParseQuery right inside an Activity?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

I have been told that putting a ParseQuery directly inside of an Activity, such as MainActivity, instead of a Helper class could pose a security threat to the application. Is this true? If so, under what circumstances? Is this the case for any database query?

Comment: It s not a security danger it's a bad architecture of application. Your views(activities) shouldn't depend on any business logic code. Working with network clients included. By the way, parse.com will be closed soon

Comment: As a relative beginner, I'm still unsure what you mean by this. Why should my views not be dependent on my business logic code? What kind of inefficiencies would such an architecture introduce? Do you have any examples? I think many people would benefit.

Also, in relation to Parse, it is now open-source and deployable on any infrastructure that runs on Node.js. I am running it on my own Azure instance and it works great!

Comment: You should dive and read about MVP on Android,   SOLID architecture principles and design patterns. It will be too broad if we'll discuss it in the SO format. The main idea is that class, which have a lot of dependencies and functional become so complicated and hard to maintain and scale in future. So I think u'll find a lot of literature about it in Google